# Two ListViews in two different fragments produce an Error

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have two fragments with two ListViews in my app. I have attempted to do the following for both ListViews in each fragment:

```
ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list1);
listView.setAdapter(new ListAdapter() {

    //Sets The Adapter

}
```

But when I run, it produces this error:

```
Can't have a viewTypeCount < 1
```

Is there a better method to what I am doing? All help is appreciated

Comment: Have you overwritten the Adapter getViewTypeCount() method ? if yes, please set it to 1 or the correct number of view types you are using

Comment: `ListAdapter` is an interface. Try one of the concrete implementation. E.g. `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: @Blackbelt it was your ArrayAdapter suggestion that fixed it. Thanks!